# NULL assignment to a structure pointer is not working through function. What to do?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to implement BST deletion. According to algorithm, we can delete a leaf directly. Now I'm assigning NULL to leaf directly and still this node remains as it is.

In the test case I gave tried to delete leaf and it is not working.

Please help!

```
struct node * delet(long data, struct node* root)
{
    int i=1;
    struct node *temp = root,*t;

    while(temp != 0)
    {
        if(data < temp->data)
        {
            i=2*i;
            temp = temp->l;
        }
        else if(data > temp->data)
        {
            i = (2*i)+1;
            temp = temp->r ;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d\n",i);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(temp->l == 0 && temp->r == 0)
    {
        temp = 0;
        return root;
    }
    else if(temp->l == 0)
    {
        temp->data = temp->l->data;
        temp->l = 0;
    }
    else if(temp->r == 0)
    {
        temp->data = temp->r->data;
        temp->r = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        t = temp;
        t = t->r;
        while(t->l != 0)
        {
            t = t->l;
        }
        temp->data = t->data;
        if(t->r != 0)
        {
            t->data = t->r->data;
            t->r = 0;
            return root;
        }
        else
        {
            t = 0;
            return root;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One issue I see is that the assignment of nodes, e.g. `temp->data = temp->l->data;` (same for right) doesn't do anything with the node, it just assigns values. This is sometimes referred to as a "dirty-delete" because there is no actual deletion of removed nodes from the tree.

Comment: And how do you call the function

Answer (score 2):

`temp = 0;` doesn't delete the leaf from the tree, just nulls a local variable.
You want to null some node's `l` or `r` in order to remove a node from the tree.
Try keeping the parent as well and once temp points to the leaf, nullify temp's parent `r` or `l`.

Same goes for `t = 0;` later on.

Note [David's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55932381/null-assignment-to-a-structure-pointer-is-not-working-through-function-what-to#comment98517688_55932381) about first releasing this memory..

For example (assuming not deleting the root):

```c
...
        if(data < temp->data)
        {
            i=2*i;
            parent = temp;
            temp = temp->l;
        }
        else if(data > temp->data)
        {
            i = (2*i)+1;
            parent = temp;
            temp = temp->r ;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d\n",i);
            break;
        }
...
    if(temp->l == 0 && temp->r == 0)
    {
        if (parent->l == temp)
             parent->l = 0;
        else
             parent->r = 0;
        // Free temp if needed
        return root;
    }
...
```

Also note that you have:

```c
    else if(temp->l == 0)
    {
        temp->data = temp->l->data;
```

Which is a dereference of a null pointer (`temp->l` is NULL), and the same thing for `temp->r == 0` case.

Then you have

```c
         temp->l = 0;
```

but you're already in a `temp->l == 0` case, so I don't think this is what you meant.

Comment: oh! I got it.. Thank you so much!!